Prove $\frac{a^2}{(1+ab)^2} + \frac{b^2}{(1+bc)^2} + \frac{c^2}{(1+ac)^2} \geqslant \frac34$ for $a, b, c > 0$ with $abc=1$

Let $a, b, c>0$ such that $abc =1$. Prove that
$$
\frac{a^2}{(1+ab)^2} + \frac{b^2}{(1+bc)^2} + \frac{c^2}{(1+ac)^2} \geqslant \frac34.
$$

I tried AG-GM, and I tried cyclic sum, but failed.
Actually I need a hint. I tried to make a cyclic sum like $\frac{1}{(b(c+1))^2}$. But not all variables are presented. I hope it is a cyclic inequality. I tried to reduce it to $\frac{a+b+c}4$ as well, because it’s obviously $a+b+c \geqslant 3$.
I tried Cauchy–Schwarz, which implies that we must prove that $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{1+ab}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{b(c+1)}\geqslant\frac32.$$ And this is easily reduced to $ab + bc + ac + a + b + c \leqslant 2(a^2c + ab^2 + bc^2)$.

Sorry, I cannot comment so it is going to be an answer.
You may want to use the standard substitution: $a=\frac{x}{y},\ b=\frac{y}{z},\ c=\frac{z}{x}$ to obtain equivalently $$\left(\frac{zx}{xy+yz}\right)^2+\left(\frac{xy}{yz+zx}\right)^2+\left(\frac{yz}{zx+xy}\right)^2\ge\frac{3}{4}.$$
Now, by Cauchy-Schwarz and Nesbitt you can conclude $$\begin{aligned}\left(\frac{zx}{xy+yz}\right)^2+\left(\frac{xy}{yz+zx}\right)^2+\left(\frac{yz}{zx+xy}\right)^2&\ge\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{zx}{xy+yz}+\frac{xy}{yz+zx}+\frac{yz}{zx+xy}\right)^2\\&\ge\frac{1}{3}\cdot\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2\\&=\frac{3}{4}\end{aligned}$$ as desired.
It is also possible to proceed in a slightly different way, i.e.
$$\begin{aligned}\frac{(zx)^2}{(xy+yz)^2}+\frac{(xy)^2}{(yz+zx)^2}+\frac{(yz)^2}{(zx+xy)^2}&\ge\frac{(zx)^2}{2(xy)^2+2(yz)^2}+\frac{(xy)^2}{2(yz)^2+2(zx)^2}+\frac{(yz)^2}{2(zx)^2+2(xy)^2}\\&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{(zx)^2}{(xy)^2+(yz)^2}+\frac{(xy)^2}{(yz)^2+(zx)^2}+\frac{(yz)^2}{(zx)^2+(xy)^2}\right)\\&\ge\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\\&=\frac{3}{4}.\end{aligned}$$
